# Function call via ajax – can't figure it out?

Tags: functions, ajax

In my header.php file I've got …

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php', 'relative' );?>";
</script>
```

In my functions.php file I've got …

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_event_list', 'get_event_list');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_event_list', 'get_event_list');

function get_event_list( $latest = true, $order = 'ASC', $return = false, $year = NULL, $cat = NULL ) {

    // Stuff of the function

}
```

In my script.js file I've got …

```
$('#year-filter .inactive').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(ajaxurl); // http://mydomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: { 
            action: 'get_event_list',
            year: '2012', //param year
            cat: 'vortraege' //param category
        },
        dataType: 'html',
        timeout: 300,
        success: function(data){
            console.log('Ajax success');
        },
        error: function(xhr, type){
            console.log('Ajax error');
            console.log(xhr + " " + type)
        }
    });
});
```

I currently get the following error in my console

> http://mydomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
>
> Ajax error
>
> [object XMLHttpRequest] timeout

Comment: have you looked at the examples on [AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) or read the documentation for [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)?

Comment: yeah, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm pretty new to javascript and ajax.

Comment: well, there is no `action` argument for `$.ajax`, `action` should be a var in `data`, and you haven't specified a `url` anywhere. copy one of the examples in Codex and work from there.

Comment: Well, I've updated my question with your feedback, however what's the url? How do I pass along the entire path to functions.php in my script.js file? And how do I add parameters to this function call?

Comment: As Mike's answer points out, your ajaxurl is wrong. If you are enqueing script.js then I'd suggest passing variables (such as ajaxurl) with `wp_localize_script`. Take a look again at the [AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Separate_Javascript_File). Secondly, is this admin-facing or public facing? If the former, ajaxurl is already defined. If the latter, your callback needs to be attached to `wp_ajax_nopriv_{$action}`. Again, check the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side).

Comment: Well, this ajax call is public, so on the frontend. I changed it to `wp_ajax_nopriv_get_event_list`. However same thing. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, it works with $.get but doesn't work with $.ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the url to the admin ajax script. You can go ahead and cheat and just use "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" as the url, it will try to locate it at the base of your domain.

However a much better method is to print the ajax url out as javascript variable in the header and then reference it in your script like so:

header.php (above the file the needs the ajaxurl):

```
<script>
    var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php', 'relative' );?>";
</script>
```

ajax script:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: ajaxurl,
    ....
```

That will have your ajax calls pointing at the right place.

To send additional data with the ajax for your php function to you should include it in the data object of the jQuery ajax method. This is the same place you've already declared the name of your php function.

For example:

```
data:{
    action: 'your_ajax_function',
    var1: 'some string',
    var2: 23,
    var3: 'another string'
}
```

Then within the php function the ajax is calling, you can retrieve them like so:

```
var1 = $_GET ['var1']; // some string
var2 = $_GET ['var2']; // 23
```

If you were using post as the ajax type instead of get, then you'd access them using the $_POST variable instead of the $_GET one.

Comment: That should really be `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php', 'relative' )`. The relative makes it work on https sites as well.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a try later. However the last question I have is how I can call parameters of my function within ajax?

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: I've updated my question. Sorry if I'm annoying, just can't figure out why my function is not getting called.

Comment: Hey up. In you're header within the script tags it needs to read **exactly** `var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php', 'relative' );?>";`. Don't replace **admin-ajax.php** with **functions.php**. All ajax calls need to go to admin-ajax.php from there it's routed to the function you reference in the data object

Comment: OK; updated my question, however doesn't change anything. Still same error. Different console.log() though.